# Update a value inside a map in list using java 8

Tags: java-8

I have the following json object. How to update factor variable if null using java 8 streams?

```
[{
    "name": "sasi",
    "surname": "test",
    "factor": 3
},
{
    "name": "sasi",
    "surname": "test",
    "factor": null
}]
```

```java
rawResponseMapList.stream().forEach(map ->map.get("factor")?null:map.put("factor", "TBD"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a convenience function `Map#computeIfAbsent` to do just that:

```
rawResponseMapList.forEach(map -> map.computeIfAbsent("factor", s -> "TBD"));
```

There is also no need to create `Stream` if you only want to replace the "factor".

Comment: I m getting misplaced constructor for this any idea?

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code or attempt, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: i put some braces extra!.. compiling

Comment: if map itselt is null it should not throw NPE